# How do I trouble shoot autoprefixer?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, autoprefixer

I'm on a rails system with the `bootstrap-sass` gem installed. This automatically pulls in `autoprefixer-rails`. I'm using `autoprefixer-rails (5.1.11)`. I can't seem to get the auto-generated prefix styles that `autoprefixer` advertises that it will automatically generate.

I know that `autoprefixer` is being loaded because I can go into `rails console` and after requiring it, I can play around with the `Class` object.

My CSS looks like this:

`&.collapsed {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}`

For example, when I remove the `-webkit-transform` style, the transform doesn't work in Safari.

**What am I missing to make `autoprefixer` work?**